# Flux - Actions being dispatched before Store register

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm building an app with react using flux as a pattern.
I'm trying to add a loader (spinner) when making an API call but it doesn't work, I guess I'm missing something. 
The flow goes like this: 
when app is loaded I'm calling initApp

```
var InitActions = {
initApp: function(){
    FooActions.getFoo();
}};
module.exports = InitActions;
```

FooActions dispatching GET_FOO Action and calling to APIService.foo.getFooByUser

```
var FooActions = {

getFoo: function(){
    var account = accountStore.getAccountData();
    var accountId = account.id;
    Dispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType: ActionTypes.GET_FOO
    });
   APIService.foo.getFooByUser(accountId);
}};
module.exports = FooActions;
```

APIService will make an ajax call and in response will trigger ServerActions.getFooSuccess or ServerActions.getFooFailed actions

```
var APIService = {
    foo: {
       getFooByUser : function(accountId){

        var url = apiUrl;
        var params = {
            "accountId":accountId
        };
       promise.post(url,params)
           .then(function(response){
                ServerActions.getFooSuccess(response);
            })
           .catch(function(response){
                ServerActions.getFooFailed(response);
            });
        }
    }
}; 
module.exports = APIService;
```

ServerActions will dispatch GET_FOO_SUCCESS or GET_FOO_Failed

```
var ServerActions = {
getFooSuccess: function(response){
    Dispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType: ActionTypes.GET_FOO_SUCCESS,
        foo: response
    });
},

getFooFailed: function(response){
    Dispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType: ActionTypes.GET_FOO_FAILED
    });
}
}
```

and the foo store is listening to these events via dispatcher.register

```
var FooStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype,{...};
Dispatcher.register(function(action){
switch (action.actionType){
    case ActionTypes.GET_FOO:
        _isLoading = true;
        FooStore .emitChange();
        break;
    case ActionTypes.GET_FOO_SUCCESS:
        _isLoading = false;
        _foo = action.foo;
        FooStore .emitChange();
        break;
    case ActionTypes.GET_FOO_FAILED:
        _isLoading = false;
        FooStore.emitChange();
        break;
    default:
    // do nothing
}});
```

Now, based on the _isLoading param I know when to display and hide loader in my foo component. for some reason the code never getting to the GET_FOO case although this action is dispatching before the API call. 
Can someone tell me why?

EDIT:
when I'm debugging the dispatcher's code I can see in dispatch function for loop

```
Dispatcher.prototype.dispatch = function dispatch(payload) {
    !!this._isDispatching ? process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? invariant(false, 'Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.') : invariant(false) : undefined;
    this._startDispatching(payload);
    try {
      for (var id in this._callbacks) {
        if (this._isPending[id]) {
          continue;
        }
        this._invokeCallback(id);
      }
    } finally {
      this._stopDispatching();
    }
  };
```

I can see the the FooStore haven't been registered yet as a dispatcher callback.
How can I make sure It's being registered before any action is being triggered?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
I'm making sure the FooStore is being registered before any cation by requiring it before I'm calling to `initApp()`